# PHP MySQLi if ID = 1 echo name from row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make something which will only display the name of the row which has ID 1 but I can't seem to get it to work. I can make it display all the names but I only want it to display the name of user ID 1. This is my current code but it doesn't work.

```
<a style="font-size: 17px; color: #ff0000;"><?php 
$q = "SELECT * FROM `Team` WHERE id =1";

$result=mysqli_query($q);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if ($row != FALSE) {
        echo '<br />$row is not false.';
        $name = $row['name'];
        echo $name;
    } else{echo "it's false :(";};
    ?></a>
```

It returns:

> it's false :(

Comment: Did you use mysqli_error() to debug?

Comment: @Bernhard Didn't get anything out of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may need the while() check on there.
Try something like:

Your database connection:

```
$servername = "YOUR_HOST";
$username = "YOUR_USER";
$password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
$dbname = "YOUR_DATABASE"; 

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    echo "There was a slight problem, please contact your webmaster before continuing.";
    exit();
}
```

Then your main file with displaying the row you want:

```
// create query
$q = "SELECT * FROM Team WHERE id = 1";

// get the records from the database
if ($result = $mysqli->query($q))
{
    // display records if there are records to display
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        // fetch the results
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
            $name = $row->name;
            echo $name;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "No results to display!<br><hr><br>";
    }

}
else
{ // show an error if there is an issue with the database query
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}
// close database connection
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: HTTP Error 500 while loading page

Comment: Fixed the HTTP Error 500 by adding ; to $q = "SELECT * FROM Team WHERE id = 1"

Comment: Sorry about that... I will fix the answer

Comment: Seems like it ends at some point, it doesn't load any HTML which comes after the PHP.

Comment: I added a last check for an else in case there's a $mysqli error. What exactly is are you trying to display, I am just kinda of guessing what your problem is, but I cannot be sure.

Comment: Seems like this line is where the problem starts and it stops doing anything after that: if ($result = $mysqli->query($q))

Comment: Does your browser give you any errors? It would be helpful. What does your database connection look like? That may also be a problem

Comment: <?php
$servername = "mysql10.namesco.net";
$username = "rumblegamin1";
$password = "***********";
$dbname = "PH717932_web";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("DEBUG: Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "DEBUG: Database connection established";

?>
Included that on every page and every pages shows Database connection established

Comment: You could try something like:
```$servername = "mysql10.namesco.net";
$username = "rumblegamin1";
$password = "***********";
$dbname = "PH717932_web"; 

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    echo "There was a slight problem, please contact your webmaster before continuing.";
    exit();
}```

Comment: The Problem has nothing to do with a while-Loop

Comment: @Bernhard I know that, I just thought to take a different approach to the problem...

Comment: @Samuel Fonseca Thanks! that worked, you're a legend!

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_query requires first parameter should be connection string and second is the query

mysqli_query($link, "your query");

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Connection-Parameter!

```
$result=mysqli_query($db, $q);
```

instead of

```
$result=mysqli_query($q);
```